# Bcrypt me da error al intentar verificar una contraseña

Tags: java

Estoy usando bcrypt para un inicio de sesión en base de datos donde almaceno un hash generado por bcrypt y luego lo verifico, probándolo resulta que falla el método de la librería pero no se el porque os dejo la depuración y el código:
codigo inicio sesion

```
public class InicioSesion {
/**
 * Intenta iniciar sesión con el nombre de usuario o correo electrónico y contraseña proporcionados.
 *
 * @param Email
 * @param Email Nombre de usuario o correo electrónico del usuario que intenta iniciar sesión.
 * @param password Contraseña proporcionada por el usuario.
 * @return id si el inicio es exitoso, en caso de fallar devuelve -3
 */
public int iniciarSesion(String Email, String password) {
    // Sentencia SQL para buscar el usuario por nombre de usuario o correo electrónico y obtener su id
    String sql;
        System.out.println( "Este es el email" + Email + " y la contraseña a verificar " + password);
        sql = "SELECT id, password_hash FROM usuarios WHERE  email = ?";

    try (Connection conn = ConexionDB.conectar();
         PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        
        // Establece los parámetros de la consulta
        pstmt.setString(1, Email);
        // Ejecuta la consulta
        try (ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery()) {
            if (rs.next()) {
                    System.out.println("usuario encontrado");
                String storedHash = rs.getString("password_hash");
                    System.out.println(storedHash + " verificacion pendiente de este hash del usuario encontrado");
                // Verifica si la contraseña coincide
                boolean passwordMatch = HashPassword.verifyPassword(password, storedHash);
                if (passwordMatch) {
                        System.out.println(rs.getInt("id"));
                    // Devuelve el id del usuario si la contraseña es correcta
                    return rs.getInt("id");
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Error al iniciar sesión: " + e.getMessage());
            
    }
    // Devuelve -1 si el usuario no se encuentra o si la contraseña no coincide
    return -3;
}
```

aqui os dejo el codigo de la clase hash:

```
public class HashPassword {
    
    // Genera el hash de una contraseña
    public static String hashPassword(String password_plaintext) {
        int workload = 12;
        String salt = BCrypt.gensalt(workload);
        return BCrypt.hashpw(password_plaintext, salt);
    }

    // Verifica una contraseña con un hash dado
    public static boolean verifyPassword(String password_plaintext, String stored_hash) {
    boolean password_verified = false;

    if (null == stored_hash || !stored_hash.startsWith("$2a$")) {
        throw new java.lang.IllegalArgumentException("Hash inválido proporcionado para comparación");
    } else {
        System.out.println("contraseña no nula y formato correcto contraseña texto plano:"+ password_plaintext + " y la contraseña hash almacenada:" + stored_hash);
        password_verified = BCrypt.checkpw(password_plaintext, stored_hash);
        if(password_verified) {
            System.out.println("verificacion hecha");
        }
    }
    return password_verified;
}


}
```

El main con el intento de inicio de sesion, aclarar que al final dejare la consola para que veais que falla en "password_verified = BCrypt.checkpw(password_plaintext, stored_hash);" de la clase hashpassword:

```
public class App {
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        CrearBaseDatos crear = new CrearBaseDatos();
        crear.Crear();
        ConsultasDB consultar = new ConsultasDB();
        System.out.println("usuarios en la base de datos");
        consultar.mostrarUsuarios();
        InicioSesion inicio = new InicioSesion();
        int variableInicio = inicio.iniciarSesion("steven@gmail.com", "123456789");
        System.out.println(variableInicio);
    
}
```

y os dejo la consola:

```
Conexi�n establecida.
Tablas creadas con �xito.
usuarios en la base de datos
Conexi�n establecida.
1   steven  steven@gmail.com    $2a$12$u/kc10n.vCnJIkxKw4nlxeQtHaEeJ3KDwUCn/LP1Eo/VVccXyEGp2
Este es el emailsteven@gmail.com y la contrase�a a verificar 123456789
Conexi�n establecida.
usuario encontrado
$2a$12$u/kc10n.vCnJIkxKw4nlxeQtHaEeJ3KDwUCn/LP1Eo/VVccXyEGp2 verificacion pendiente de este hash del usuario encontrado
contrase�a no nula y formato correcto contrase�a texto plano:123456789 y la contrase�a hash almacenada:$2a$12$u/kc10n.vCnJIkxKw4nlxeQtHaEeJ3KDwUCn/LP1Eo/VVccXyEGp2
-3
```

Comment: Para la contraseña "123456789", el hash guardado es incorrecto. Según https://bcrypt-generator.com/ no hay un match correcto entre ellos dos. Prueba a generar nuevamente un hash para la misma contraseña, y validalo en esta herramienta.

Comment: te dejo otra que confirma la situación. Estás seguro que el hash guardado es correcto ? https://bcrypt.online/

Comment: Otro agregado, te sugiero, durante desarrollo, usar el ELSE de if(password_verified) para verificar de inmediato que pasa con la verificación, que valor te retorna, y que cosas intentó comparar.